# How to return multiple times from a function?

Tags: php

I am trying to return values in php for sql injection, but the return is stopping my function. Here is the example:

```
function ex($input) {
    if (strlen($input) > 5) 
    {
        return $input;
    }
    return ":the end";
}

echo ex("helloa");
```

When I use return inside the function it ends it and ex("helloa") == "helloa" not "helloa:the end" like I want it to.

Comment: The whole POINT of returning is to end the function.

Comment: That's what `return` does.... functions are meant to terminate on the return... if you don't want to terminate the function, then don't use return

Comment: And what is your desired behavior?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, what exactly do you want? That's what return does...

Comment: syntax error in example, it should be `echo at_sign_finder2("helloa");`

Comment: I updated things a little to explain things. I know the return function terminates. What should I use not to terminate?

Comment: @user2840324: see my answer. You can use an array as a stack to keep adding values you actually want to return, and then later pick values from that array.

Comment: @Stoic This is a perfect answer, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Concatenating Strings in a Function

When you want to have multiple strings, and actually wanna concatenate (or join) them. You can keep on adding them together in a variable and then, return that variable at the end of the function.

```
function ex($input) {
    $return = "";
    if (strlen($input) > 5) 
    {
        $return .= $input;
    }
    $return .= ":the end";

    return $return;
}

echo ex("helloa");
```

---

## Using an array to *pseudo-return* multiple values

If you really want to return multiple values/strings, you can instead tell the function to return an array. You can only return one output though from a function.

```
function ex($input) {
    // this array acts as a container/stack where you can push
    // values you actually wanted to return
    $return = array();
    if (strlen($input) > 5) 
    {
        $return[] = $input;
    }
    $return[] = ":the end";

    return $return;
}

// you can use `implode` to join the strings in this array, now.
echo implode("", ex("helloa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function ex($input) {
    return (strlen($input) > 5 ? $input : '') . ":the end";
}
```